# On which criteria would the browser consider using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as content-type?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, axios

I am using Axios as a Xhr client. When sending a request, if the header contains a 'Content-Type' which is related to a `form`, Axios will delete it and [let the browser set it.](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/503418718f669fcc674719fd862b355605d7b41f/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L16)

The problem is that the browser sets `multipart/form-data` which raises an error on the server I am posting to.

I am wondering on which criteria would the browser consider setting the content-type back to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Is there any other header to specify to force the browser using `x-www-form-urlencoded` (I thought about `content-disposition` or something like that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome will consider sending a `x-www-form-urlencoded` if the request body contains an URLSearchParams as seen [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/97#issuecomment-223650368)
For instance using Axios:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```